# Pandas Shift Rows and Backfill (Time-Series Alignment)

Tags: python, pandas

I have time-series customer data with running totals that look like this:

```
       week1 | week2 | week3 | week4 | week5
user1     20      40      40      50      50
user2      0      10      20      30      40 
user3      0       0       0      10      10
```

I am looking for spending trends, so I want to shift all my rows to start at week one and backfill with their last value, resulting in:

```
       week1 | week2 | week3 | week4 | week5
user1     20      40      40      50      50
user2     10      20      30      40      40
user3     10      10      10      10      10
```

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this quite compactly as:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:]. \
    apply(lambda row: row.shift(-np.argmax(row > 0)), axis=1). \
    ffill(axis=1)
```

but there is a lot going on in that 1 statement

`iloc[:, 1:]` selects all rows, and all but the first column (since we are not interested in touching the user column. My answer *assumes* that the user is a column, if the user is an index instead, then you can remove both the occurrences of `[:, 1:]` in this answer.

`apply(<function>, axis=1)` applies the provided function to each *row*

`np.argmax` *[as I used here]* finds the first index in an array that meets a condition. in this case the first position with value > 0

`row.shift(-np.argmax(row > 0))` shifts the row backwards dynamically, based on the position of the first greater-than-0-value.

`ffill` forward fills null values with the last non-null value.

Comment: The shift works great but I believe the ffill needs the parameter axis = 1. Very cool! and thanks so much!!

Comment: I saw this question belatedly. Added an alternative answer just in case you are need of simpler alternative method

Answer (score 1):

Nice answer from @Haleemur Ali.

Alternative would be to [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) backwards.

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'user':['user1','user2','user2'],'week1':[20,0,0],'week2':[40,10,0],'week3':[40,20,0],'week4':[50,40,10],'week5':[50,40,10]})
df.set_index('user', inplace=True)#.rename_axis(None)
df
```

Replace zero with NaN

```
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df
```

Then just interpolate

```
df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=1,limit=None,inplace=True,limit_direction='backward',limit_area=None,downcast=None,)
```